# Sybase: DateTime to char (timestamp)

Tags: datetime, timestamp, sybase, sap-ase

I have to convert getdate() TO char
I was using below to set in order to insert the timestamp of batch process
*set a_batch_id = (select convert(char(12), getdate(), 12))*
I would get 160309 for 03/09/16 but what i need is 39201644418486 while getdate() fetches 3/9/2016 4:44:18.486 PM

I am not worried about the order yymmdd but is it possible to add the hours and minutes as mentioned above.

anything close to 160309444 should be fine, with seconds even better.

Comment: I think you are a little overboard. MySQL and SyBase are different products, and PLSQL is typically associated with Oracle.  Which database are you working with and remove the other tags.

Comment: yes, i was trying to trying to get higher radar :) edited it now

Answer (score 1):

From researching, it appears you are running Sybase, and you do not want a typical YYYYMMDD type of formatting, but mmddyyyyhhMIss  [Look at Sybase Date Conversions](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm)

```
convert(char(32), getdate(), 139 )
```

which would give the format of

```
"mmm dd yy[yy] hh:nn:ss.ssssss"
```

Then, you would wrap that in another replace command to strip out the unwanted.  In this case, removal of space, colon and decimal point...

```
replace( replace( replace( convert(char(32), getdate(), 139 ), " ", "" ), ":", "" ), ".", "" )
```

FEEDBACK

With respect to using this as a "batch id", consider having auto-increment columns as an INTERNAL ID to help keep joins to foreign keys within database clear.  If you want to have an alternate "key" lookup, such as WHEN, or search criteria, yes, add that to the "Batch" table.  What happens if you want some other identifier.  Your internal IDs would have no impact.  Having a date/time stamp on a "batch" table would allow you to query, sort, group by in reports too.

Looking more into the Sybase documentation, this too might work for you as "mmm" returns the character month.  This is longer, but should work for you.  The year will return 4 digits, so I did not have to explicitly pre-add a leading zero and then take the right side.

ex: if the month was 1, it would create "01".
ex: if month was 11, it would create "011" and thus the right 2 = "11"

Similarly for Day, Hour, Minute, Second.

```
select
     right( '0' + trim( str( month( getdate() ))), 2 )
   + right( '0' + trim( str( day( getdate()))), 2 )
   + right(       trim( str( year( getdate() ))), 4 )
   + right( '0' + trim( str( hour( getdate()))), 2 )
   + right( '0' + trim( str( minute( getdate()))), 2 )
   + right( '0' + trim( str( second( getdate()))), 2 )
```

Now, if this gets you the most of what you need, great.  Now, if you need that millisecond value, just add on one more + component for below, but test and adjust the position depending on how sybase works the return value.

```
+ substring( convert( varchar, getdate(), 37 ), charindex( convert( varchar, getdate(), 37 ), '.' ), 4)
```

Since the convert mode 37 returns " hh:nn:ss.ssssss" but no guarantee if single or double-digit value for the hour, minute, seconds (that I can test), I am looking for the '.' as the position offset to start the substring and getting only the milliseconds.  If the decimal is included, change the charindex() to charIndex() +1 so it is removed from the returned string.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am getting below error when I just run the *select convert(char(12), getdate(), 139 )* part  [Error Code: 281, SQL State: ZZZZZ]  139 is not a valid style number when converting from DATETIME to a character string.

Comment: basically i am looking to use the datetime as batch id of the job run so I would need hours and minutes along with date of run. 0311161143 would be representing job run at 03/11/2016 11:43 AM it can even be '031120161143'

Comment: @max, revised answer for clarification opinion.

Comment: *That was my first choice for batch ID but this is the requirement.*
I kind of used two styles of getdate to combine them for our requirement.<!-- *select @ Bdt = convert(char(6), getdate(), 12)
select @ Bd =  convert(char(12), getdate(), 108) * *UPDATE #temp
  set a_batch_id = @ Bdt+@ Bd --> I still have trouble with ':' in the hh:mm trying to use str_repace but it seems not supported in sybase ase

Comment: @max, Did you try my last statement with the full replace nested with the get date converted?  Try them individually for testing.  I widened the convert string to 32 characters

Comment: @max, revised answer to get hard formatted values of full date/time

Comment: thank you! sorry for late response.. Sybase ASE doesnt seem to make things easier to remove ':' using replace or str_replace..

Comment: @max, that is fine... did you even try the select at the bottom of the question where I was building up each of the components directly.  That might work closer for you.

Comment: I get an error 'trim' is not a built-in function name

Comment: @max, Apparently no trim directly, so you may try LTRIM() (for left-side trim) as numbers might be left-filled space before actual digits.  You might also need to go LTRIM( RTRIM( value )) to trim both left and right sides.

Comment: fortunately or unfortunately the vendor system didn't allow more that six characters as batch id, i just had to update table with (select convert(char(12), getdate(), 12))